# Django logging not showing argument

Tags: python, django, logging, django-admin

I have this line in a custom django-admin command:

```
logger.info("%d records updated", records_updated)
```

When I run the command, the log file and console output show what I would expect:

```
[2011-09-02 03:49:31,405] INFO::(27041 140698227433576)::update_records - 5 records updated
```

However, the email to the admin shows

```
INFO: %d records updated  #This is the subject and body of the email the admin receives
```

This is my logging info in the settings.py file:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s::(%(process)d %(thread)d)::%(module)s - %(message)s'
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'email_admins': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        'include_html': True,
        'formatter': 'default',
    },
    'admin_console': {
        'level':'INFO',
        'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'default'
    },
    'null': {
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        'formatter': 'default',
    },
    'file_handler': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'formatter':'default',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
        'filename':'logs/Project_log',
        'when':'midnight',
        'interval':1,
    },
    'request_handler': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/django_request.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter':'default',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['email_admins', 'file_handler', 'admin_console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    },
    'django': {
        'handlers':['null'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level':'INFO',
    },
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['email_admins', 'request_handler'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': False,
    },
}
```

}

Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`logger.info("%d records updated" % records_updated)`

Maybe u should write like this?

Comment: This breaks the grouping of messages in sentry, Is there a different solution to this ?

Comment: While this technically will work, it will not fix the problem that the author had since the `logging` methods support (and encouraged by pylint) what the author originally wrote.